# foreach line in word add char - Powershell 4.0

Tags: powershell

I am trying to add on each line in ms word "* " char ($doc2 in the code).

```
$objWord = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$objWord.Visible = $true
$filename = 'D:\test.docx'
$objDocument = $objWord.Documents.Open($filename)

$LETable = $objDocument.Tables.Item(1)
$LETableCols = $LETable.Columns.Count
$LETableRows = $LETable.Rows.Count
$content2 = $LETable.Cell(6,2).Range.Text -replace '\r\a','' -creplace '(?m)^\s*\r?\n',''
$hl = "`n"
$content3 = $LETable.Cell(7,1).Range.Text -replace '\r\a','' -creplace '(?m)^\s*\r?\n',''
$content4 = $LETable.Cell(7,2).Range.Text -replace '\r\a','' -creplace '(?m)^\s*\r?\n',''
$doc2 = $objWord.Documents.Add()
$objWord.Selection.typetext("$content2$hl$content3$content4")

foreach ($doc2.Range().Text) | ####Something like that?
```

Comment: You're doing a bunch of replacements in table cells, what does that have to do with adding "* " to anything?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I want to add "*" to each row..something like `foreach ($Line in $doc2.Range().Text) { 
$Line = $line.Insert(0,'* ') 
$Line += '"' 
}
Write-Host $Line` But I don't know insetad of 0 what to enter for each row. Thanks

Comment: There are numerous loop constructions that may help. Did you check SO documentation? http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/powershell/1067/loops-in-powershell#t=201608171640117139203

Comment: Request is unclear. Do you mean each line break (as in each paragraph)? Or are you referring to each line as in line wrapping? Because that would depends on window size, resolution, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I mean each new line for each string. So I guess I need to ask where is a new \r\n and then to put "*" on it.